# Vanishing of a certain double sum of roots of unity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fourier-transform, abelian-groups, roots-of-unity, exponential-sum

For $d \in 2\mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq k,l \leq d-1$ the following double sum turned up in my computations:
$$
f(k,l)=\sum_{x=0}^{d-1} \sum_{y=0}^{d-1} \varepsilon(x+y)\exp\left( \frac{2 \pi i\cdot(k x + l y)}{d}\right).
$$
Here, $\varepsilon(z)=1$ for $0 \leq z \leq d-1$ and $\varepsilon(z) = -1$ for $d \leq z \leq 2d -2$.

Using Mathematica, I noticed that $f(k,l)\neq 0$ iff $k\cdot l=0$ or $k=l$ (at least for the cases I looked at). This would simplify further computations significantly for me, so my question is:

If this is true in general, why so? I was trying some finite Fourier transform yoga, but I didn't succeed.

Progress so far: Maybe it is helpful to turn $x+y$ into a summation variable. For this we need to expand the double sum as follows (I hope I made no mistake) so that instead of one "square matrix" of double indeces we get three "triangles" of double indeces:

\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{d-1} \sum_{y=0}^{d-1}&=\sum_{x=0}^{2d-1} \sum_{y=0}^{2d-1-x} -\sum_{x=d}^{2d-1} \sum_{y=0}^{2d-1-x} -\sum_{y=d}^{2d-1} \sum_{x=0}^{2d-1-y}\\
&=\sum_{z=0}^{2d-1} \sum_{y=0}^{z} -\sum_{z'=0}^{d-1} \sum_{x'=0}^{z'} -\sum_{z'=0}^{d-1} \sum_{y'=0}^{z'},
\end{align}
where $z=x+y$, $z'=x+y-d$, $x'=x-d$ and $y'=y-d$. So in the last two summands we have $\varepsilon=1$ and in the first summand we can split the first sum in positive part and a negative part. Using the geometric series then it should follow.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The same statement holds for all terms with $\epsilon=1$ and all terms with $\epsilon=-1$ separately, so it might be easier to look at one at a time.